# Import excel file and display DataGridView selected rows to another DataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to import excel file and load it into my `datagridview1`.

After showing the content of the file inside my `DataGridView`, I want to select the row and transfer it into my second `DataGridView`.

Please anyone can help me how to fix my code? Because I'm getting error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + "Sheet1" + "$]", conn);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
   this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
   }
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow selRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
   {
   dataGridView2.Rows.Remove(selRow);
   dataGridView2.Rows.Add(selRow);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something more like this

```
var selected_rows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow selRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().ToArray())
{
      selected_rows.Add(row);
}
foreach(var row in selected_rows){
      dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
      dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

C# doesn't typically allow modification of a collection while that collection is being enumerated. You can normally circumvent this problem by using the initial loop to simply gather the objects you wish to operate on, and then you can iterate through that collection of objects. Something like this

I would also imagine that calling `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` should suffice. There's no need to convert to a strongly typed array, but that may be more of a syntactic preference than anything.

Try this out and let me know how it works

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but the data that taken from datagridview1 and variables still not view in the datagridview2 when i click the move button (button3_click).I just made one open file button for excel file, one load button to show the excel file content into datagridview1 and one button to move the selected row from datagridview1 going to datagridview2.